# How to disable a combobox from another user control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two user controls `Import` and `DailyReport`.The Import user control contains a combobox and `DailyReport` has some event like edit and save.When i click on edit button I want to disable that combox which is on `Import` user control. `DailyReport` user control is upon the `Import` user control.

I have tried following code in DailyReport usercontrol.

```
public delegate void EditButtonClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event EditButtonClickEventHandler OnEditClick;

private void actionControlDRD_EditEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OnEditClick != null)
    {
        OnEditClick(sender, e);
    }
}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You can either define a `public void DisableCombobox()` method or set the Combobox' accessor attribute to `public` instead of the default `private`.

Comment: are both user controls on same aspx page?

Comment: Its a winforms not aspx

Comment: @AmitKumar : Both user control are in same form?

Comment: @Sumeshk: Yes, Both are on same form.

Comment: @AmitKumar : check my answer and if it is use ful modify your code

Comment: @AmitKumar : if it is helpful mark my answer as solution

Comment: did any of our answers solved your problem if not please put more code and description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the first form I would have something like this.

```
public delegate void ButtonClickedEvent(object sender);
public event ButtonClickedEvent Form1ButtonClicked;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Form1ButtonClicked != null)
    {
        Form1ButtonClicked(sender);
    }
}
```

In the second form I would have something like this.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.Form1ButtonClicked += new Form1.ButtonClickedEvent(f_Form1ButtonClicked);
    f.Show();
}

void f_Form1ButtonClicked(object sender)
{
    comboBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void EnableDisableControls(Control.ControlCollection Controls, bool state)
{
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = state;
        if (c is ComboBox)
        {
            // do something here with comboBoxes 
        }

        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            this.EnableDisableControls(c.Controls, state);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create **one and only one**  object for **Import** , **DailyReport** user control in the form constructor

add two methods in the form

1. Accept `Import` object as argument

> Void DisableDailyReportCombo(Import objImport)
>
> {
>
> objDailyReport .Combobox.enabled=false;
>
> }

1. Accept `DailyReportobject` as argument

> Void DisableImportCombo(DailyReport objDailyReport )
>
> {
>
> objDailyReport .Combobox.enabled=false`
>
> }

and handle the appropriate functionality in each method

ie,when an event raise from `Import` user control call the **DisableImportCombo** method with argument `DailyReport` object and disable the combobox